ArrayInput Input Values Sum in React Admin
I would like to sum the values of each input in my ArrayInput. Could someone tip me please?
Here is my ArrayInput component:
<ArrayInput source="team_capacities" label="Capacités par équipe">
                <SimpleFormIterator inline>
                  <ReferenceInput source="team_id" reference="teams">
                    <SelectInput optionText="name" label="Équipe *" />
                  </ReferenceInput>
                  <NumberInput
                    source="capacity"
                    label="Capacité *"
                    onChange={handleTeamCapacityChange}
                    value={teamCapacity}
                  />
                </SimpleFormIterator>
              </ArrayInput>

My handleTeamCapacityChange:
const handleTeamCapacityChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const teamValue = event.target.value;
    const newValue = teamValue === '' ? 0 : parseInt(teamValue);
    setTeamCapacity(newValue);
  }

I can easily see ONE value of an input but I don't know how to sum them.
Thank you,
Alexis
It's my first post.

Please add more details, dummy-data, data-type, example by which we can understand what is input & what is expected output.

One easy way to access the form values in react-admin and to derive a state (such as a sum) from them is to use the useWatch hook. I recommend you give that a try.
